# Windows 8 loses access to disk partitions

Tags: windows, windows-8

I have a Windows 8 setup on a laptop with two disks with two partitions each. Windows 8 loses access to all three partitions except the one on which the OS is installed.

There is no telling when and how it does lose access. Even running as administrator could not recover drive ownership.

Comment: Whilst it may be driving **you** crazy, there's no need for you to SHOUT at us.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. Though I'd like to help you out. You should first check your `Group policy`. If you think that's fine then attach your laptop HDD on a friends laptop and see if it can be accessed there. Lastly you should check with a good antivirus with latest virus definitions to ensure that you don't have a virus on board.

Answer (score 0):

## David Heffeman , I had no intention to shout at anybody and did not realize it was uppercase until later... that is an antipatic type of answers a so called moderator should not post. you could have spent the time to try to help.....

back to the subject. I still do not know the reasons for losing access to drives . I do suspect this however... after several times I put windows in sleep mode (via charm > Power button) or simply close the lid and that would put it to sleep also, it appears that recovering loses some rights and privileges to files.
what I think I saw happen with almost 100% certainty is that both times this happed , i also was on battery which died.

now I am not sure which sequence and number of times laptop went into sleep mode or lost power to begin lose drive access privileges...

I have noticed that in some cases drive owner is completely lost and in others owners are still there and users including administrator too with no change to their rights , but still could not access it. this leads me to believe it is a kind of corruption in windows recovery from sleep mode procedures ...

Recovering access to drive: the only way I was able to take or assign ownership is by going into safe mode and re-assigning drive ownership , user privileges .....

it works every time...

Comment: You're raising your voice again...